# Compile LLVM Pass on windows under visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

I compile llvm myself using what i found in internet with config like this `cmake -S llvm\llvm -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld" -DLLVM_EXPORT_SYMBOLS_FOR_PLUGINS=On -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=X86 -Thost=x64`
and what i found that i need to use `LLVM_EXPORT_SYMBOLS_FOR_PLUGINS` on window or i not get plugins to build. It seem worked, i found some "*.exp" files in `c:\installocation\LLVM\lib`.

I followed faq on llvm page about pass developing https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html but CMakeLists.txt in there not suitable for window environment but i found another suited for windows.

But now i can't understand how can i should build and configure pass. What i did:
Create out of source directory `C:\users\culpr\Documents\test1`

Create `Hello.cpp` in the above directory with the code from LLVM manual page

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"

using namespace llvm;

namespace {
struct Hello : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID;
    Hello() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

  bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
    errs() << "Hello: ";
    errs().write_escaped(F.getName()) << '\n';
    return false;
  }
}; // end of struct Hello
}  // end of anonymous namespace

char Hello::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<Hello> X("hello", "Hello World Pass",
                         false /* Only looks at CFG */,
                         false /* Analysis Pass */);

static RegisterStandardPasses Y(
    PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
    [](const PassManagerBuilder &Builder,
       legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) { PM.add(new Hello()); });
```

Create `CMakeLists.txt` with the content

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)
project(llvm-tutor-hello-world)
set(LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR "" CACHE PATH "LLVM installation directory")

# Add the location of LLVMConfig.cmake to CMake search paths (so that
# find_package can locate it)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${LT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/cmake/llvm/")

# FIXME: This is a warkaround for #25. Remove once resolved and use
# find_package(LLVM 11.0.0 REQUIERED CONFIG) instead.
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

# HelloWorld includes headers from LLVM - update the include paths accordingly
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Load LLVM's CMake macros and functions
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}")
include(AddLLVM)

if( NOT LLVM_REQUIRES_RTTI )
  if( NOT LLVM_REQUIRES_EH )
    set(LLVM_EXPORTED_SYMBOL_FILE     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Hello.exports)
  endif()
endif()

if(WIN32 OR CYGWIN)
  set(LLVM_LINK_COMPONENTS Core Support)
endif()

add_llvm_library( LLVMHello MODULE BUILDTREE_ONLY
  Hello.cpp

  DEPENDS
  intrinsics_gen
  PLUGIN_TOOL
  opt
  )
```

Now i try to make build files, from visual studio 2019 developer prompt:

```
cd C:\users\culpr\Documents\test1
cmake -DLT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM" .
```

And getting errors like this

```
C:\Users\culpr\Documents\test1>cmake -DLT_LLVM_INSTALL_DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM" .
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30137.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30137.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "opt" configuration "Debug".


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "opt" configuration "Release".


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "opt" configuration
  "MinSizeRel".


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "opt" configuration
  "RelWithDebInfo".


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Visual studio project get generated despite of errors, but when trying to build it:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opt-NOTFOUND.obj' [C:\Users\culpr\Documents\test1\LLVMHello.vcxproj]
```

Here is full build log https://pastebin.com/axU15prD

How i shoud configure this in CMakeFiles.txt `IMPORTED_IMPLIB not set for imported target "opt"` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the code to be in the **question post** itself, not linked to the other site. Please, [edit] your post and add the code into it. You may also find useful [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev hi, that will do? or build log too

Comment: It is sufficient to have at least the error message in the question post, as you already have. Not sure whether the whole log is needed to be included to the post.